# How to limit the number of decimal places in scientific notation?

Tags: lightningchart

Under type "linear-highPrecision", when the number is large, the axis ticks will be converted into a scientific notation like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbU5v.png).

**I wonder if there is a way to shorten the number of decimal places after the scientific count, or simply hide the ticks whose the decimal places are too long like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73b6H.png)?**

```
.ChartXY({
  container: `${this.chartId}`,
  theme: this.$myTheme,
  defaultAxisX: {
    type: 'linear-highPrecision'
  },
  defaultAxisY: {
    type: 'linear-highPrecision'
  }
})
```